# Bucle que me repita introducir un valor

Tags: bash, shell-script

Tenía la duda de la forma en que se puede hacer un bucle repitiéndome el echo de "Escribe un valor" hasta que llegado un número que sea el 99 salga del script. (Se usará el bucle, pero no sé donde ponerlo, si antes del if o no.

Os dejo el código:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Escribe un valor"
read A
if [ $A -ne 99 ]
then
echo "El cuadrado de $A  es cuadrado=`expr $A \* $A`"
else
echo "Error"
fi
```

Comment: No, pero gracias.

Comment: la pregunta enlazada (tuya) contiene una respuesta cuyo contenido es casi exactamente lo que pides

Comment: El problema es que no es lo que quiero ahora exactamente, por eso.

Answer (score 0):

Tendrias que englobar todo tu codigo en un bucle de esta manera

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    echo "Escribe un valor"
    read A
    if [ $A -ne 99 ]
    then
        echo "El cuadrado de $A  es cuadrado=`expr $A \* $A`"
    else
        exit
    fi
done
```